# Google sheet query with header and detail

Tags: google-sheets

I have a file with identical rows of which I want to make "headers" like in the link below.
Is that possible with formula or script?

Thank you.

[Test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BGLIAHybcc-Ml7YI3JdsBlC3tB2-rTQCwIinB7Pmx9E/edit#gid=1859063314)

Answer (score 1):

I used the condition of a changing group to build an array of row numbers that can "sort into" the original array to display the header and an empty row between sections.  I used this formula.  You can find it in A2 of the MK.Idea tab.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({Data!F2:G\ROW(Data!F2:F);IF(Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B&Data!C2:C&Data!D2:D&Data!E2:E<>Data!A1:A&Data!B1:B&Data!C1:C&Data!D1:D&Data!E1:E;{Data!A2:A&"-> "&Data!B2:B&"-> "&Data!C2:C&"-> "&Data!D2:D&"-> "&Data!E2:E\SPLIT(" |"&ROW(Data!A2:A)-0,1;"|";0;0)};IF(Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B&Data!C2:C&Data!D2:D&Data!E2:E<>Data!A3:A&Data!B3:B&Data!C3:C&Data!D3:D&Data!E1:E;IFERROR(SPLIT(" | |"&ROW(Data!A2:A)+0,1;"|";0;0));))};3;1);9^9;2)
```

Comment: Hello. You did a great job. Do you think (even if you wrote that seems not possible) you could find a solution to "spill over" column A on column B? Do you think it's possible to combine your formula with a query of which what you did would be the result? My sheet "Data" is en fact the result of a Query. It would be well if that query could result directly in your sheet "MK.Idea".  I am sorry for not asking that in the beginning. Best regards. Benoît Lucas (sorry fod bad english, I am French).